Humanity has long been at war with aliens. Protagonist's elderly former chemistry teacher has brain wired to control a spaceship
The war has been going on as long as anyone can remember. The aliens have an advantage in that they have living creatures that are spaceships and can reproduce so do not need to be built.
The humans want to try a spaceship directly controlled by a human brain wired into it. They are not sure where to find a volunteer. The protagonist thinks of his former chemistry teacher. He is old and ill, likely not to live much longer. He is still very smart and able. The former chemistry teacher agrees. He makes changes to the wiring before his brain is wired up to the ship.
The old chemistry teacher's brain flies off with his new spaceship body instead of going to fight for humanity in the war.

His chemistry teacher sounds like a dick

A P.K. Dick, perhaps.

This sounds exactly like Mr. Spaceship a short story by P.K. Dick, first published in 1953.
In the story, Earth is at war with an alien race called the "Yuks" who do not use mechanical spaceships, but instead have a technology based on living matter. To compete with this, researchers decide to create their own type of lifeform-based ships. From the summary on wikipedia:

One day a team of researchers led by Philip Kramer decide to build a
spaceship which is powered by a human brain and they find the ideal
candidate in Kramer's old professor, a dying man who volunteers to
donate his brain to the project.

On the test run, however, the professor takes control of the ship and departs for outer space. Later it returns to collect Kramer and his wife:

On board the ship, the professor's brain informs them that they will
be looking for a new planet to colonize to try and start a new and
better world. The professor decides on this colonization because he
sees no hope in humanity and what he feels it has become: a species
which desires, above all else, war.

The full story is available at Project Gutenberg.
